# How to center DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

Any clue? The code below doesn't work properly...

Thank you!

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Name="dg1"   Grid.Row="0" >
     <DataGridTemplateColumn  Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="First Name"></Label>
             </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                 <Label Content="{Binding FirstName}" />
              </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

UPDATE:

Solution of @ArsenMkrt is great but I am facing some strange vertical lines...

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `HeaderStyle` instead of `HeaderTemplate`

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

Comment: Cool! But I am facing this error now: Error    'localprimitives' is an undeclared namespace.

Comment: Awesome!!! Please have a look at my question... There are some vertical lines are wrapping the header word...

Comment: please try to remove HeaderTemplate, or set  <Label HorizontalAlignment="Streatch" .../>

Comment: did you remove HeaderTemplate? does it help?

Answer (score 12):

try this It works for me to center the header without any issue.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

Answer (score 6):

not sure if still helps but with this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>                            
    </Style>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

will center the header without the vertical bar issue

Answer (score 2):

All the answers here did solve the problem, but the theme was different from rest of the column headers. So A little change did the trick for me. Here it is if anyone is still looking for it.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

Comment: This works, and was helpful to me because I also had a different underlying theme. However, I would like to retain my existing theme. How can I do that? Thank you.